# Grooming questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions

At the moment of writing this we have a couple of identical questions on the site:

- [one](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3287/is-there-any-project-planning-software-out-there-for-windows-that-doesnt-look-l) originally posted at PMSE
- and [another one](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3291/is-there-any-project-planning-software-out-there-for-windows-that-doesnt-look-u) migrated from other site

A default action should be voting to close one of them since it is an exact duplicate (which I did). The problem is it takes 5 votes to close the question and, well, I'd say that we don't have enough people to think about such activities. On the other hand it doesn't seem appropriate to flag this question, as that's what dup close reason was designed for.

My question is what we can do with such cases? Flag so we bring moderators' attention up? Leave it as it is? I don't feel well with the latter by the way. Something else?

Comment: Hi Pawel, you're our all time top contributor in the reputation leagues and in editing. What's your take on what the site needs in terms of improvement and gaining more of a following? Do you know what we can do to encourage more editing and quality improvements? Please weight in on the most recent meta questions if you have the time :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I merged the two questions together. I merged the question with the most close votes with the one with no close votes. This merges all answers, as well as the comments for those answers, to the target question.

Leaving a comment on the question with a reason why it should be closed, flagging the question (if it's really bad) and voting to close as a duplicate are all great actions to take in this situation. If close voters specify which question is the duplicate; oftentimes, a moderator can merge any answers from the closed question with the original.